# python sort json object to different payloads based on date

Tags: python, json

I have a standard JSON file with the below structure:

```
db = {
    "db_records": [
                      {
                      "webhook": 'NA',
                      "xx": {"foo"},
                      "yy": {"otherfoo"},
                      "id": "UID1234567@2019-03-20T08:20:54.634838"
                      },
                      { ...},
                      { ...},
                      { ...},
                      { ...},
                  ]
}
```

My question is, how do i sort this JSON based on the date within the `id`?

I thought of creating a loop to extract the `datetime` from `id` with the below code:

```
for i in db['db_records']:
    conv_date = i['id'].split('@')[1].split('T')[0]
    obj_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(convo_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

This provides me with the date for each JSON item. But is it possible to sort the JSON object into different payloads based on the date in `id`?

eg:

```
# Everything in this payload are entries during the date: '2019-03-20'
db_payload1 = {
    "db_records": [
                      {
                      "webhook": 'NA',
                      "xx": {"foo"},
                      "yy": {"otherfoo"},
                      "id": "UID1234567@2019-03-20T08:20:54.634838"
                      },
                      { ...},


    ]
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

db = {
    "db_records": [
                      {
                      "webhook": 'NA',
                      "xx": {"foo"},
                      "yy": {"otherfoo"},
                      "id": "UID1234567@2019-03-20T08:20:54.634838"
                      },
                      {...},
                      {...}
                  ]
}

def get_id_date(record):
    id_datetime = record['id'].split('@')[-1]
    return datetime.strptime(id_datetime, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')

print(sorted(db['db_records'], key=get_id_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.search` to search for the date, parse the string into datetime format using `datetime.datetime.strptime`, then sort by the `.date()`:

```
from re import search
from datetime import datetime
from pprint import pprint

db = {
    "db_records": [
        {
            "webhook": "NA",
            "xx": {"foo"},
            "yy": {"otherfoo"},
            "id": "UID1234567@2019-03-20T08:20:54.634838",
        },
        {
            "webhook": "NA",
            "xx": {"foo"},
            "yy": {"otherfoo"},
            "id": "UID1234567@2019-03-19T08:20:54.634838",
        },
        {
            "webhook": "NA",
            "xx": {"foo"},
            "yy": {"otherfoo"},
            "id": "UID1234567@2019-03-18T08:20:54.634838",
        },
    ]
}

sort_key = lambda x: datetime.strptime(
    search(r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}", x["id"]).group(), "%Y-%m-%d"
).date()

pprint(sorted(db["db_records"], key=sort_key))
```

Which Outputs:

```
[{'id': 'UID1234567@2019-03-18T08:20:54.634838',
  'webhook': 'NA',
  'xx': {'foo'},
  'yy': {'otherfoo'}},
 {'id': 'UID1234567@2019-03-19T08:20:54.634838',
  'webhook': 'NA',
  'xx': {'foo'},
  'yy': {'otherfoo'}},
 {'id': 'UID1234567@2019-03-20T08:20:54.634838',
  'webhook': 'NA',
  'xx': {'foo'},
  'yy': {'otherfoo'}}]
```